# How we can create instance of ConfigurationDbContext in the external library?

Tags: identityserver4

How we can create instance of ConfigurationDbContext in the external library to add clients dynamically? Actually we using EntityFrameworkCore with IdentityServer4 to store configuration data.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming that you are using .NET Core, all you need to do is to make sure the class where you need to access the ConfigurationDbContext is created via dependency injection and then inject `IConfigurationDbContext` in the constructor.

Here's an example.

If you need the `IConfigurationDbContext` in the `ClientsService` class, register it for dependency injection like this:

```
public static IServiceCollection AddDataServices(this IServiceCollection services)
{
    return services
        .AddTransient<IClientsService, ClientsService>();
}
```

Then inject the context in the `ClientsService` constructor:

```
internal sealed class ClientsService : IClientsService
{
    public ClientsService(IConfigurationDbContext context)
    {
        (...)
    }
}
```

Since Identity Server registers the context at startup, this works just like you want.